# Selenium webelement providing empty text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium and webscraping/web interactions in general so I apologize if this is a simple error that I'm missing. I'm currently running a small piece of code to interact with a website and encountering an issue when trying to get the text names of some webelements

The output I expect to receive would be the species names of both plants with the words "plant name" following them. For some reason I can get both of the names when I cycle through the species list all on its own (y in species loop), but I lose the second name and get an empty text when I try and loop through it with this extra code (specie in species loop). This is the output I actually get in my console.

Loaded!

500

<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>

Carex mesochorea

Carex michauxiana

Carex mesochorea plant name

plant name

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time
plantlist = [['Plant species']]
z_code = 1001
perpanel = 500


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://bonap.net/TDC/")

zipcode = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a"))
    )

print("Loaded!")

time.sleep(1)
zipcode.click()
time.sleep(1)

zipcode_type = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/input[1]"))
    )

zipcode_type.send_keys(str(z_code).zfill(5) + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)


dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div/select"))
dropdown.select_by_value(str(perpanel))



time.sleep(2)
Items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'tl-a tl-i')]")
print(len(Items))
species = Items[len(Items)-2:len(Items)]
print(type(species[0]))

for y in species:
    print(y.text)


for specie in species:
    print(specie.text + " plant name")
    ItemName = specie.text[2:len(specie.text)-1]
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(specie)
    )
    time.sleep(1)
    specie.click()




time.sleep(10)
```

edit: It looks like deleting the specie.click() command fixes the issue, but I have absolutely no idea why